# html table, using Javascript for a little adventure game

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, dom-events

I started coding in January of this year, and I wanted to create a small game to train some of my new skills, and I am facing an important question at the very start.

I want to create a table, let's say 20 by 20.
Knowing that a lot of tiles in this table will be unique (have unique CSS features), I need to be able to manipulate these CSS attributes of each tile individually.

I could only think of creating a `<table>` in html so I can access every `<tr>` and `<td>` easily.

I know you can create tables in a much simpler and straight forward way using Javascript. The thing is, at this early stage I have trouble visualizing, how I can manipulate the CSS attributes of a specific tile.

Any tips on how I can approach this?

Comment: how would you go about identifying an individual cell? Row/Column intersection? Sequential numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pure CSS way to do this is to use *nth-child* to access each table rows and columns.

An example, say you want to target the 2nd row and 3rd column, you could do something like this:

```css
tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So what this does is to find the 2nd table row and the 3rd data column in it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
/*
    utility function to create a new DOM element of type (`t`), 
    assign various attributes (`a`) and append as a child of `p`
*/
const create=function(t,a,p){
    let el = ( typeof( t )=='undefined' || t==null ) ? document.createElement( 'div' ) : document.createElement( t );
    let _arr=['innerHTML','innerText','html','text'];
    
    for( let x in a ) if( a.hasOwnProperty( x ) && !~_arr.indexOf( x ) ) el.setAttribute( x, a[ x ] );

    if( a.hasOwnProperty('innerHTML') || a.hasOwnProperty('html') ) el.innerHTML=a.innerHTML || a.html;
    if( a.hasOwnProperty('innerText') || a.hasOwnProperty('text') ) el.innerText=a.innerText || a.text;
    
    if( p!=null ) typeof( p )=='object' ? p.appendChild( el ) : document.getElementById( p ).appendChild( el );
    return el;
};

/*
    shorthand utility to find a cell by querying 
    the data attributes for row and column
*/
const getcell=function(r,c){
    return document.querySelector('td[ data-row="'+r+'" ][ data-col="'+r+'" ]');
};





let gs=10;  // grid size
let o={};   // empty options

let tbl=create('table',o,document.getElementById('grid-container'));

// manipulate the CSS variable which helps govener grid display
let root=document.documentElement;
    root.style.setProperty( '--size', gs );

    
// construct rows and columns
for( let a=1; a <= gs; a++ ){
    let row=create('tr',o,tbl);
    for( let b=1; b <= gs; b++ ){
        create('td',{'data-row':a,'data-col':b},row);
    }
}


// manipulating individual cells
getcell(3,3).style.background='lime';
getcell(5,5).classList.add('banana');
```

```css
:root{--size:10;}
table{ width:100%; }
td{width:calc( calc( 100% / var( --size ) ) - 4px );height:calc( calc( 100vh / var( --size ) ) - 4px );border:1px solid red;margin:2px; }

.banana{background:yellow}
```

```html
<div id='grid-container'></div>
```

Admittedly the display here depicts non-square cells - it was cobbled together very quickly but I hope it shows how you can manipulate css for the cells.

Answer (score 1):

An html table is ok for what you're trying to do, but I'd rather go with a CSS Grid, that it's a very powerful evolution of what tables offer. It'll simplify your layout manipulation and is a sure bet to learn it for the future. At the begining of internet as we know it, html tables where used as layout for entire websites. It was even common to have nested tables go unnamable levels just to adjust the visualization to the pixel. Now, all this has gone, first with flex layout, and now with CSS grid, that is well supported across all major browsers.

I recommend that you take a look to some CSS grid resouces out there and try to go with it. Some good ones are:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

https://learncssgrid.com/

https://gridbyexample.com/

If you need to access each individual cell there're many approaches:

- You can put an id to each individual cell that indicates it's position:

  ```
  <div id="r15c8"></div>
  <div id="r16c8"></div>
  ```

or Excel style:

```
  <div id="E14"></div>
  <div id="E15"></div>
```

and that on...

- You can use the :nth-child() selectors of CSS
- Or you can use the CSS grid features to assign names to each cell or even a group of them with the areas feature.

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.board {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.board > div {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #20262e;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.board > div:nth-child(7) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <div>A1</div>
  <div>B1</div>
  <div>C1</div>
  <div>D1</div>
  <div>A2</div>
  <div>B2</div>
  <div>C2</div>
  <div>D2</div>
  <div>A3</div>
  <div>B3</div>
  <div>C3</div>
  <div>D3</div>
  <div>A4</div>
  <div>B4</div>
  <div>C4</div>
  <div>D4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can assign unique class name to each of your grid or if you feel you are going to have a lot of grids to do that manually, then you can generate them using javascript and assign a unique class

class names can go as:

```
grid00 grid01 grid02
grid10 grid11 grid12
grid20 grid21 grid22
```

now you can access simply using grid index